# PostgreSQL JSON data type used as NOSQL, But VIEW as Relational Data Structure

Tags: postgresql, view, relational-theory, nosql, json

Could I create a VIEW from the JSON data type but have it as a relational structure?

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM json_test;
```

Results

```
[
    {
        "name": "Roy",
        "Country": "USA",
        "hobby": "Swim",
        "address": "Church Street",
        "sex": "M"
    },
    {
        "name": "Roy",
        "Country": "USA",
        "hobby": "Cricket",
        "address": "Amsterdam",
        "sex": "F"
    },
    {
        "name": "Anam",
        "country": "Greece",
        "hobby": "Polo",
        "address": "MG Road",
        "sex": "M"
    }
]
```

Then to create the VIEW would be something like (not sure if/how to do this)

```
CREATE VIEW normalized AS 
SELECT name, country, hobby, address, sex 
FROM JSON data
```

Then I could query the view with something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM normalized
```

Result set

```
name  | country | hobby   | address       | sex  
------+---------+---------+---------------+----
 Roy  | USA     | Swim    | Church Street | M
 Roy  | USA     | Cricket | Amsterdam     | F
 Anam | Greece  | Polo    | MG Road       | M
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 5):

As you have multiple rows inside the JSON column, you need a function that returns a set. This can be done using the `json_to_recordset()` function:

```
select j.*
from json_test, 
     json_to_recordset(json_data) as j(name text, country text, hobby text, address text, sex text);
```

Because this is an anonymous record type, you must explicitly define each column. Probably not a big thing if you want to put that into a view. Note that your sample data would not return a value for the `Country` keys in your JSON data, only for the one named `country` because the matching between column names and JSON keys is case-sensitive.

If you don't want to create a view, you can shorten the above using a custom type:

```
create type person_t as (name text, country text, hobby text, address text, sex text);

select j.*
from json_test, 
     json_populate_recordset(null::person_t, json_data) as j;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91b85/1

Answer (score 0):

```
**If you are popular the bank with a json already getting the data
```

Exmple:**

```
insert into person(name,Country,hobby,address,sex) 
select name,Country,hobby,address,sex
from json_populate_recordset(null::person, 
'
[
 {"name":"Roy","Country":"USA","hobby":"Swim","address":"Church Street","sex": "M" },
 {"name":"David","Country":"USA","hobby":"Swim","address":"Church Street","sex": "M" }
]
');
```

Comment: The original question is asking how to construct a view on existing stored JSON data that returns it in a standard row/column format. You're showing how you can insert data in JSON format into a regular table, which is a different thing.